# Calling a function from cloud code

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, parse-platform

I need to run a function from my Parse.com afterSave method but I'm new to javascript and something with the signature doesn't seem to work.

The function I'm trying to call follows the [Parse.Cloud reference](https://www.parse.com/docs/js/symbols/Parse.Cloud.html#.run):

```
<static> {Parse.Promise} Parse.Cloud.run(name, data, options)
```

This is the function I want to call:

```
function funcToRun(data, response) {
    console.log("running funcToRun");
}
```

I'm trying to call it like this:

```
var data = "FilmName";
Parse.Cloud.run('funcToRun', data, "");
```

But no matter what I do the `funcToRun` doesn't get called.

Answer (score 0):

`Parse.Cloud.run` runs a Cloud Function [1], not a regular JavaScript function. To make your code work, you need to define the function in the correct way.

In your case it would look like this:

```
Parse.Cloud.define('funcToRun', function(request, response) {
    console.log('running funcToRun');
    response.success();
});
```

[1] https://www.parse.com/docs/cloudcode/guide#cloud-code-cloud-functions

Comment: Bjorn, but how do I pass parameters into my function? I want to pass in the request but when I try Parse.Cloud.run("funcToRun", request); I get a Failed with: Uncaught Parse.Objects not allowed here. If I simply call Parse.Cloud.run("funcToRun") the function is called but there are no params in the request.

Comment: It is all in the docs, check the link from my answer and read about the cloud functions. It contains all the info you need to pass in data.

Comment: Björn, I can't find any reference in that doc to what types of parameters can be passed into a cloud function, nor any reference to the fact that you can't pass in a Parse Object. The docs must have changed since you posted this (there are a number of other errors in them). Is this documented somewhere?

Comment: Yeah, they changed it since, you can have a look here https://www.parse.com/docs/cloudcode/guide#cloud-code-cloud-functions. There is an example for calling a Cloud Function in Cloud Code that also shows how to pass in parameters